# Override Cypress.config().baseUrl with environment variable (process.env)

Tags: cypress

I was to set the baseURL of my cypress tests to be read from `.env` file.

I can't set it directly in the `cypress.json` file.
And when I try to use `cy.visit(process.env.MYAPPURL)`, I get an this error

> cy.visit() must be called with a url or an options object containing a
> url as its 1st argument

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can leave `cy.visit()` empty but you just need to set this env CYPRESS_BASE_URL with the base url instead like this for example:

```
CYPRESS_BASE_URL=$VUE_APP_BASE_URL
```

check this for explanation https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables